# Excel Date Format

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to make a line chart, as you can see the some of the boxes have #N/A, the formula for the boxes are:

```
=IF($C5='Match Up'!$G$2,NA(),'9 or 10'!$B5/'9 or 10'!$C5)"
```

The `#N/A` are not showing up on my graph however, the date associated with the `#N/A` is. I have tried to make the dates a text on the graph yet they are still showing up. Any ideas on how to hide the dates not associated with a value? The data is dynamic and will change so I cannot filter or hide the columns with N/A

[[image: 1]]

Comment: The data is dynamic and could change, I do not want to keep changing the filters

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1428230/edit) instead of adding information in comments. What other constraints do you have?

Comment: If the chart is an XY (scatter) chart, the X axis is a time scale.  It will show dates at a specified interval as a scale, regardless of whether there are data points corresponding to those interval points.  It's just like inch markings on a ruler; the numbers are just reference points, independent of the specific measurement you're taking.  The data will be plotted proportional to its date, even if you have missing data.  If this is a line chart, the dates have no real meaning.  They're just labels for points on the graph that are stacked in order.  (cont'd)

Comment: As long as there is a table entry for each month and the data is sorted in date order, the chart will reflect the timing by coincidence.  If dates are excluded, the chart will reflect the sequence, but it won't be displayed in proportion to time.  The chart will show the general shape of the pattern (up or down relative to the previous value), but won't accurately reflect when those values occurred.  So if you're interested in, say, how fast are things changing, you lose the ability to see that.  Can you clarify your objective in that regard, and the type of graph?

Comment: It it is a line chart. the data is percent of something each month does that help?